# Axes Swapping in higher degree numpy arrays

Tags: arrays, numpy, swap, axes

So I was embarking on a mission to figure out how the numpy swapaxes function operates and reached a sort of a roadblock when it came to swapping axes in arrays of dimensions > 3.
Say

```
import numpy as np
array=np.arange(24).reshape(3,2,2,2)
```

This would create a numpy array of shape (3,2,2,2) with elements 0-2. Can someone explain to me how exactly axes swapping works in this case, where we cannot visualise the four axes separately? 
Say I want to swap axes 0 and 2.

```
array.swapaxes(0,2)
```

It would be great if someone could actually describe the abstract swapping which is occurring when there are 4 or more axes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How do you 'describe' a 4d array?  We don't have intuitions to match; the best we can do is project from 2d experience.  rows, cols, planes, ??

This array is small enough to show the actual print:

```
In [271]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(3,2,2,2)
In [272]: arr
Out[272]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3]],

        [[ 4,  5],
         [ 6,  7]]],


       [[[ 8,  9],
         [10, 11]],

        [[12, 13],
         [14, 15]]],


       [[[16, 17],
         [18, 19]],

        [[20, 21],
         [22, 23]]]])
```

The print marks the higher dimensions with extra [] and blank lines.

```
In [273]: arr.swapaxes(0,2)
Out[273]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 8,  9],
         [16, 17]],

        [[ 4,  5],
         [12, 13],
         [20, 21]]],


       [[[ 2,  3],
         [10, 11],
         [18, 19]],

        [[ 6,  7],
         [14, 15],
         [22, 23]]]])
```

To see what's actually being done, we have to look at the underlying properties of the arrays

```
In [274]: arr.__array_interface__
Out[274]: 
{'data': (188452024, False),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (3, 2, 2, 2),
 'strides': None,    # arr.strides = (32, 16, 8, 4)
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'version': 3}
In [275]: arr.swapaxes(0,2).__array_interface__
Out[275]: 
{'data': (188452024, False),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (2, 2, 3, 2),
 'strides': (8, 16, 32, 4),
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'version': 3}
```

The `data` attributes are the same - the swap is a view, sharing data buffer with the original.  So no numbers are moved around.

The shape change is obvious, that's what we told it swap.  Sometimes it helps to make all dimensions different, e.g. (2,3,4)

It has also swapped 2 `strides` values, though how that affects the display is harder to explain.  We have to know something about how shape and strides work together to create a multidimensional array (from a flat data buffer).